# JavaScript intellisense comments not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, comments, intellisense

I am currently documenting a JavaScript project with Visual Studio compatible XML intellisense comments.

E.G.

```
///<summary>This is a JavaScript XML comment</summary>
```

On my work machine, if I type `///` Visual Studio automatically generates the XML that I need to comment, but on my personal machine, it's not working. I'm using the same version of Visual Studio on both machines.

Any ideas on why it's not working? maybe I'm missing a vsix extension or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INSTALL THE JSCRIPT VSDOC STUB GENERATOR [2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e122a031-d748-41e9-87b1-7b56d8610d8b) / [2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0cb7304b-ad78-4283-ba2b-42804657fcdd)**

Comment: I know with this extension it will work, but the team member that seats behind me, don't has that extension and it works for him to...very strange. (I saw his extensions list)

Comment: I believe ReSharper also has this functionality, though it's a paid extension.